# Cannot import dump to MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL dump file created on MySQL 5.6. When trying to import it to a MySQL 5.7 database, I receive the following error:

`[ERROR in query 9] Cannot add foreign key constraint`

I've used `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` to check the details, and it says:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2016-02-21 18:47:32 0x700000d51000 Error in foreign key constraint of table mydatabase/articles:
 FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `e_companies` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci:
Cannot resolve table name close to:
 (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

In other words, it says that it interprets a whole part of the SQL statement as table name.

This is how the SQL dump looks like:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `articles`;

CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `perex` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `text` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `status` enum('draft','published') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'draft',
  `author_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `image` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `pin` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` enum('article','case-study','interview','recording','infographic') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'article',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `articles_slug_unique` (`slug`),
  KEY `articles_company_id_foreign` (`company_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `full` (`title`,`perex`),
  CONSTRAINT `articles_company_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `e_companies` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

LOCK TABLES `articles` WRITE;
....
```

This is a dump produced by MySQL 5.6 and works perfectly, except on my MySQL 5.7. Does anyone have any ideas what can be the cause of this strange error?

Comment: And you don't use funny options with `mysqldump`? (Despite the fact that I don't know which ones are _funny_.) I think all those starting with `--skip` are funny.

Comment: But to be serious again: Is `articles` the first table in your dump? Does the dump do `create database`? Did it _ever_ work with your 5.7 server?

Comment: Nope. Just this: mysqldump -h192.168.123.123 -umyuser -p mydatabase > mydump.sql

Comment: Ok, sorry, then I have almost no clue. I'd try `mysqldump -h192.168.123.123 -umyuser -p --databases mydatabase > mydump.sql`. This adds `drop/create database` statements. Perhaps that helps, but it's only guessing.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is the FULLTEXT KEY is causing the problem (i have had a lot of issues while upgrading from 5.x to 5.7 because of FULLTEXT KEYs...)

I would recommend to remove this part of your create table, and apply it later via a classic ALTER.

If this works, it would be interesting to compare the initial dump (5.6 one) with a new dump performed on the 5.7 server.

Hope this helps !